# Python: performance of for loops over a list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, generator, list-comprehension

In the instance where I iterate a list comprehension via a for-loop:
**Is the list comprehension cached when the for loop is executed, or is the list re-generated on every execution?**

In other words, would these two examples perform differently?

```
for x in [list comprehension]
```

vs

```
list_comprehension = [list comprehension]
for x in list_comprehension
```

I could use an iterator, which I believe uses a generator, but I'm just curious about the Python for-loop execution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
for x in [list comprehension]:
```

the entire list is built before the for loop starts. Its basically equivalent to the second example except for the variable assignment.

Answer (score 2):

a list comprehension returns a list.  The only difference between your two examples is that you're binding the output list to a variable in the second.

A *generator* expression returns an iterator, which means that:

- It won't get evaluated until you use it
- If you want to use it more than once you'll have to generate it each time.

Answer (score 0):

with this command : `list_comprehension = [list comprehension]` actually you create another pointer to that part of memory that array have been saved !

So the `for` loop is same in tow case ! see this Demo:

```
>>> a=[1,2,4]
>>> b=a
>>> b
[1, 2, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 4]
>>> a.append(7)
>>> a
[1, 2, 4, 7]
>>> b
[1, 2, 4, 7]
```